# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 550 - Storybook with Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, storybook

I'm trying to add a storybook to my project but I get this error

> Adding Storybook support to your "Angular" app
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 550
> at JSON.parse ()
> at readFileAsJson (C:\Users\Marouen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\17500\node_modules@storybook\cli\dist\helpers.js:60:15)
> at getAngularAppTsConfigJson (C:\Users\Marouen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\17500\node_modules@storybook\cli\dist\generators\ANGULAR\angular-helpers.js:47:38)
> at editAngularAppTsConfig (C:\Users\Marouen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\17500\node_modules@storybook\cli\dist\generators\ANGULAR\index.js:23:70)
> at generator (C:\Users\Marouen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\17500\node_modules@storybook\cli\dist\generators\ANGULAR\index.js:52:3)
> at runGenerator (C:\Users\Marouen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\17500\node_modules@storybook\cli\dist\initiate.js:162:37)
> at installStorybook (C:\Users\Marouen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\17500\node_modules@storybook\cli\dist\initiate.js:206:10)
> at _default (C:\Users\Marouen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\17500\node_modules@storybook\cli\dist\initiate.js:277:10)
> at Command. (C:\Users\Marouen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\17500\node_modules@storybook\cli\dist\generate.js:34:566)
> at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (C:\Users\Marouen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\17500\node_modules@storybook\cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:413:31)

When I try to start

```
npx -p @storybook/cli sb init
```

I checked the Angular.json with a JSON linter and the file is validated! Does anyone know how to solve this??

Comment: Maybe your JSON is invalid?

Comment: @Justinas I copy pasted in https://jsonlint.com/ and it validated the file

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue due to trailing comma in angular.json Please check again or share your solution.